# What is the best strategy to store sensitive data on hyperledger composer?

Tags: security, hyperledger-composer

What is the best approach to store sensitive data like users login credentials or other information on hyperledger composer. 
Does just denying its access in ACL file to other users would do the work?

Answer (score 1):

Storing sensitive data is not generally recommended to be stored on the blockchain (eg Fabric). Certainly not login credentials. Rather, the best practise is to store a 'hash' of the data, or file/image/PDF and have a reference to the source image client side.

See also discussions here also (below) they may be of assistance to broaden your understanding and issues even if you choose to encrypt and put on the blockchain.

[Is there any mean to crypto data of ledger in Composer business network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971697/is-there-any-mean-to-crypto-data-of-ledger-in-composer-business-network?rq=1)

[Securing confidential information in Hyperledger Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154652/securing-confidential-information-in-hyperledger-composer)

and this Fabric thread -> [How can the transaction certificates in Hyperledger be used to enforce privacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684593/how-can-the-transaction-certificates-in-hyperledger-be-used-to-enforce-privacy?rq=1)